# Assign license to specified user B when successful checkout by user A

Tags: commerce

I want users on my site to be able to buy a file download for other users and anonymous users. I have added line item fields to the checkout form so the current user can specify the email address of the recipient of the purchased file.

How do I grant license to the file paid for to the recipient based on the supplied email address? I tried to use rules, but I did not see any rules action that could issue license to the recipient user or email.

Comment: You probably need to clarify what license means. I assume that it is an entity, and entities can be created via Rules actions.

Comment: License is paid access to files uploaded as products. Am using drupal commerce and commerce file to implement this, commerce file extends commerce license which issues the license to the users.